# grep filter all lines plus one before each hit

Tags: bash, grep, filter

I want to parse some output so I exclude all lines that contain either `foo` or `bar`, as well as all lines immediately preceding those lines. For example:

```
echo "
1 some line
2 line to exclude because the next line has one of the terms
3 line with foo
4 line to exclude because the next line has one of the terms too
5 line with bar
6 another line
">InputFile
```

I want the output:

```
1 some line
6 another line
```

I tried `cat InputFile|grep -v "foo"|grep -v "bar"`, but it doesn't exclude line 2 and 4, and the option `-B1` for the line before doesn't work either.

Comment: In your example output you don't show the blank line that occurs before and after the 1 and the 6 lines. Do you intend that these should be included in the output too, or should the be filtered out?

Comment: For me that is irrelevant. I just made an example to get the clue.

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: @rubo77 - shorter: [`sed '$!N;/\(foo\|bar\)/!P;D' infile`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the more verbose version of essentially the same thing **@1_CR** posted above and @ ash showed at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HmYbHJh7), hopefully using more readable syntax:

```
awk '{
        lastLine = currentLine;
        currentLine = $0;
    }

    /foo|bar/ \
    {
        getline currentLine
        next
    }

    NR > 1 \
    {
        print lastLine;
    }

    END \
    {
        if ( currentLine !~ /foo|bar/ )
            print currentLine;
    }
    ' InputFile
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps `awk`?

```
awk 'BEGIN{a = "foo"}; a !~ /foo|bar/ && $0 !~ /foo|bar/{print a};
{a = $0};END{if(a !~ /foo|bar/){print a}}' InputFile
```

Comment: that seems to work, although hard to read ;) Is it not possible to achieve that with grep?

Comment: And how would I exclude "bar" also?

Comment: @rubo77, updated to exclude `bar`. It shouldn't be that hard to parse if you realize that the variable `a` is being used to track the previous line. So as each line is processed, a decision as to whether to print the previous line is being made based on the contents of the current and the previous line.

Comment: @ash - 1_CR rejected your attempt to make this more readable. As a compromise I've created a pastebin of your edit which I agree is important since the answer to a novice `awk`'er can be hard to digest. http://pastebin.com/HmYbHJh7

Comment: @rubo77 - see my comment above to ash, it includes a url to a more readable version of this answer.

Comment: @slm, I rejected ash's attempt at making this more readable on the grounds  that his readable version is worthy of upvoting and should go in a separate answer

Comment: @1_CR - Oh, OK. Well I'll leave it to ash to do as he wishes. Thanks for clarifying. I wasn't calling you out or anything, just closing the loop with ash so he knew what was up, and also to not leave the OP in the lurch 8-).

Comment: @ash - see comments above by myself and 1_CR.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
grep -v "$(grep -E -B1 "foo|bar" InputFile)" InputFile
```

Comment: One thing to be wary of with this answer - it uses the lines in the InputFile that will be removed as regular expressions.  As long as those lines never contain `.`, `*`, etc, it should be ok.  `grep -a` should prevent that from being a problem.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing - if the line before a `foo` or `bar` is ever repeated elsewhere in the file, it will be discarded from there as well.

Comment: @ash: so would there be a better solution somehow?

Comment: awk is a better way to go, as 1_CR answered.  If you like, I can make that answer more readable; it's currently written very terse; more readable will likely be less so.

Comment: thanks for your example: http://pastebin.com/HmYbHJh7 Maybe you can make this as a separate answer, I will upvote that one then