# How to print a line if that line or the next line do not contain a particular string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, solaris

Input.txt:

```
    8B0C
    remove
    8B0D
    remove
    8B0E
    remove
    8B0F
    8B10
    remove
    8B14
    remove
    8B15
    remove
    8B16
    remove
    8B17
    remove
    8AC0
    8AC1
    remove
    8AC2
    remove
    8AC3
    remove
    8AE4
    8AE5
    8AE6
    remove
```

Desired output:

```
    8B0F
    8AC0
    8AE4
    8AE5
```

I want to print a line if that line or the next line does not contain 'remove'. I am using solaris 5.10, KSH.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed '$!N;/remove/!P;D' infile
```

This pulls the `N`ext line into pattern space (if not `!` on la`$`t line) and checks if pattern space matches `remove`. If it doesn't (means none of the two lines in the pattern space contains the string `remove`) it `P`rints up to the first `\n`ewline character (i.e. it prints the first line). Then it `D`eletes up to the first `\n`ewline character and restarts the cycle. This way, there are never more than two lines in the pattern space.

---

It's probably easier to understand the `N`,`P`,`D` cycle if you add `l` before and after the `N` to look at the pattern space:

```
sed 'l;$!N;l;/remove/!P;D' infile
```

so, using only the last six lines from your example:

```
    8AC3
    remove
    8AE4
    8AE5
    8AE6
    remove
```

the last command outputs:

```
    8AC3$
    8AC3\n    remove$
    remove$
    remove\n    8AE4$
    8AE4$
    8AE4\n    8AE5$
    8AE4
    8AE5$
    8AE5\n    8AE6$
    8AE5
    8AE6$
    8AE6\n    remove$
    remove$
    remove$
```

Here is a short explanation:

```
cmd        output            cmd
```

```
l     8AC3$                  N # read in the next line
l     8AC3\n    remove$      D # delete up to \n (pattern space matches so no P)
l     remove$                N # read in the next line
l     remove\n    8AE4$      D # delete up to \n (pattern space matches so no P)
l     8AE4$                  N # read in the next line
l     8AE4\n    8AE5$        # pattern space doesn't match so print up to \n
P     8AE4                   D # delete up to \n
l     8AE5$                  N # read in the next line
l     8AE5\n    8AE6$        # pattern space doesn't match so print up to \n
P     8AE5                   D # delete up to \n 
l     8AE6$                  N # read in the next line
l     8AE6\n    remove$      D # delete up to \n (pattern space matches so no P)
l     remove$                # last line so no N 
l     remove$                D # delete (pattern space matches so no P)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '
    !/remove/ && NR > 1 && prev !~ /remove/ {print prev} 
    {prev = $0} 
    END {if (!/remove/) print}
' Input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="remove\n"; ORS="" }
      RT{ print gensub("[^\n]*\n$","","") }; !RT{ print }' file
```

The above method does not read Records *line-by-line*, rather it reads *multi-line* Records from one Record Separator (RS) to the next (or end-of-file) – the `RS` being the "remove" line itself (including its trailing `\n).

The `!RT` test is needed for when the last line is not an `RS` line.
`RT`, a *gawk-ism*, is the actual text of the current record's `RS`.
`gensub` is also a *gawk-ism*.

If you need to check for a marker line that ***matches*** "remove" anywhere in the line, vs. a line which ***equals*** "remove", then just change the Record Separator to:

```
`RS="[^\n]*remove[^\n]*\n"`
```

---

Output:

```
8B0F
8AC0
8AE4
8AE5
```