# How to edit next line after pattern using sed?

Tags: sed

Using `sed`, how do I search for a line ending with `foo` and then edit the next line if it starts with `#bar`?

Or put another way, I want to remove a comment `#` from the next line if it starts with `#bar` and the previous line ends in `foo`.

For example:

```
This is a line ending in foo
#bar is commented out
There are many lines ending in foo
#bar commented out again
```

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/^foo\n#bar/foo\nbar/' infile
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`N;P;D`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550/22142) cycle and attempt to substitute each time:

```
sed '$!N;s/\(foo\n\)#\(bar\)/\1\2/;P;D' infile
```

this removes the leading `#` from `#bar` only if it follows a line ending in `foo` otherwise it just prints the pattern space unmodified.

---

[Apparently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285160/how-to-edit-next-line-after-pattern-using-sed#comment496751_285162), you want to uncomment US mirrors in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` which is a whole different thing:

```
sed -e '/United States/,/^$/{//!s/^#//' -e '}' /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

This will uncomment all mirrors in the US section  in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`

Comment: This prints the lines, but it is not removing the '#'. It may be my implementation. I am using Arch Linux and am attempting to remove all the comments from the United States servers in the mirrorlist file.

Comment: It does for me (archlinux too) so there's something wrong with your file. Maybe you have spaces, try with `sed '$!N;s/\(foo[[:blank:]]*\n\)#\([[:blank:]]*bar\)/\1\2/;P;D' infile`

Comment: I was looking at this website and I commented out all the servers, and then wanted to only uncomment United States servers: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors#Sorting_mirrors

Comment: @CompSci-PVT - lol, that's a whole different question dude... You want to uncomment all commented lines that follow a pattern inside a paragraph. See my updated post though you should edit the question to reflect your actual requirements.

Answer (score 21):

```
sed '/foo$/{n;s/^#bar/bar/;}'
```

is a literal translation of your requirement. `n` is for `next`.

Now that doesn't work in cases like:

```
line1 foo
#bar line2 foo
#bar
```

Or:

```
line1 foo
line2 foo
#bar
```

As the line that is pulled into the pattern space by `n` is not searched for `foo`.

You could address it by looping back to the beginning after the next line has been pulled into the pattern space:

```
sed '
  :1
  /foo$/ {
     n
     s/^#bar/bar/
     b1
  }'
```

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use `P;D` for one line only solution?

Comment: @cuonglm, it looks like the `P;D` approaches are already covered in other answers. This answer shows the _direct translation of the requirement_ approach (search for `foo$`, get the next line, substitute) along with its limitations.

Comment: Excelent solution(s).  Could you explain why the first one fails in those special cases, and why the second one works?  BTW: a one line equivalent to the second one would be: `sed ':1;/foo$/{n;s/^#bar/bar/;b1}'`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito, that wouldn't be portable/standard. You can't have anything after `:1` or `b1` because in many `sed` implementations including the original UNIX implementation, that *anything* would be taken as part the branching label's name (that even used to be required by POSIX).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sed -e '$!N;/foo\n#bar/s/\(\n\)#/\1/;P;D'
```

Comment: Using this, I get an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unknown option to 's'

Comment: @CompSci-PVT: Missing the `;`, updated.

Comment: I am sure your answer is supposed to work, but it is not removing the '#' on my machine. Same as above answer. I will have to investigate more.

Comment: @CompSci-PVT: Check you line ends with `foo` or `foo` with trailing spaces?