# Bash, match string and then replace everything after character in next line

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, replace

What I am looking to do is find a match and then replace everything after character in the next line.

Example file contents:

```
  super_service:
    app_version: 1.02
  duper_service:
    app_version: 4.0.1
  happy_service:
    app_version: 2.03
  turbo_service:
    app_version: 1.28.0
```

Expected outcome: What I am looking to do is match duper_service for example, and then replace everything after its' "app_version: " with a new version I define, 4.0.2 for example. I am able to do this with awk but need to write the change to the file.

Comment: `cp originalFile original.back && awk '{ .... }' originalFile > output.tmp && mv output.tmp originalFile`

Comment: See also [How to edit next line after pattern using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285160/how-to-edit-next-line-after-pattern-using-sed)

Answer (score 0):

`sed` seems a good candidate for this:

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*duper_service:/ { N; s/[^:]*$/ 4.0.2/ }' file.txt
```

Explanation: when the "duper_service:" line is encountered, next line is appended and whatever ends that line, after the colon, (`[^:]*$`) is replaced with "4.0.2".

The `-i` option changes the file in-place. It's a GNU sed extension.

Comment: This is great but a version may not always start with a number.

Comment: Read the title again, "replace everything after character in next line".

Comment: That looks great, it is not working for some reason though.

Comment: Removing the ^ seems to have done the trick.

Comment: No, that one is good, "^duper_service" was where the problem occurred for me. Thank you so much for your wonderful command and time spent. This is wonderful!

Comment: My pleasure! Ok, I understand now why the first version didn't work: there are space characters before "duper_service". Answer edited accordingly. It's better not to `/duper_service:/` as this regex may also match other lines like "extra_duper_service:"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
sed -i '/duper_service/!b;n;c\ \ \ \ app_version: 4.0.2' file.txt
```