# How can I fix lines broken in wrong places?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

My text file looks like this:

```
This is one
sentence that is broken.
However this is a good one.
And this
one is
somehow, broken into
many.
```

I want to remove the trailing newline character for any line which is followed by a line starting with a lowercase letter.

So this should be:

```
This is one sentence that is broken.
However this is a good one.
And this one is somehow, broken into many.
```

How can I do this?

Edit: There are some really good answers here, but I chose to accept the first one that worked *and* was earliest. Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: LaTeX?  The problem is that you don't really state the rules for proper sentence breaking.  Do you want to put everything up to and including end-of-sentence punctuation on a single line?  But what if you have a long sentence and it runs off the edge of your display window?

Comment: I wonder what you're really trying to solve?  Perhaps you should use markdown formatting?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks for the reminder! I had missed out somehow. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
awk '$NF !~ /\.$/ { printf "%s ",$0 ; next ; } {print;}' file
```

where

- `$NF !~ /\.$/` match line where last element do not end with a dot,
- `{ printf "%s ",$0` print this line with a trailling space, and no line feed,
- `next ; }` fetch next line,
- `{print;}` and print it.

I am sure there will be a `sed` option.

Note: this will work with line ending in a dot, however condition in sentences beginning with upper case letter won't get merged. See Stéphane Chazelas's answer.

Comment: If you like clever (many don't) `awk 'ORS=$NF~/\.$/?"\n":" "'`

Answer (score 10):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v ORS= '{print (NR == 1 ? "" : /^[[:lower:]]/ ? " " : RS) $0}
             END {if (NR) print RS}'
```

That is, do not append the record separator to each line (ORS empty). But *prepend* a record separator before the current line if not on the first line and the current line doesn't start with a lowercase letter. Otherwise prepend a space character instead, except on the first line.

Comment: When I run this some pairs of words are concatenated. For example `And thisone issomehow, broken intomany.` I don't know `awk` but should lines be joined with `<space>` in addition to `RS`? Or is this user error?

Comment: @BLayer, well spotted, thanks. Should be fixed now.

Comment: No problem. Though one wonders where the 11 upvotes came from. Must be nice to have people just assume you're always right. ;)

Answer (score 4):

In perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $input = join("", <>);
$input =~ s/\n([a-z])/ $1/g;
print $input;
```

Technically you wanted to replace "newline followed by lower-case letter" with "space and-that-lower-case-letter", which is what the core of the above perl script does:

1. Read in the input to a string `input`.
2. Update the `input` variable to be the result of the search & replace operation.
3. Print the new value.

Comment: good one!! translated to one-liner, `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n([a-z])/ $1/g'` and can similarly be done with GNU sed as `sed -zE 's/\n([a-z])/ \1/g'` (assuming input doesn't have null characters)

Comment: @Sundeep, or `perl -Mopen=locale -0777 -pe 's/\n(?=[[:lower:]])/ /g'` for it not to be limited to ASCII letters.

Answer (score 4):

With `sed` you could use a `N;P;D` cycle (so as to always have two lines in the pattern space and if the first character after the newline is lowercase then replace the newline with a space) and a `t`est - that way after each `s`ubstitution you restart the cycle:

```
sed -e :t -e '$!N;/\n[[:lower:]]/s/\n/ /;tt' -e 'P;D' infile
```

Comment: I think I see what's going on here, but an expanded answer would help those of us who don't use sed loops and pattern spaces very often.

Comment: @Joe - what do you mean by _"not using the pattern space very often"_ ? That's where almost all operations take place - the hold space is a "storage space" - you can't do anything with the data while it's there. Anyway, I have explained in detail how [a `N;P;D` cycle works here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550) so I won't go over it again. The difference here is the `t`est - to check whether something was replaced or not - if the test is successful then we branch to the top of the script, otherwise it means nothing was replaced and `P;D` are executed. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can do this is:

```
perl -lpe '$\ = /\.$/ ? $/ : $"' data
```

wherein: `$\` => `ORS`,  `$/` => `IRS`= `\n`,  `$"` = `space`

```
perl -pe '$_ .= <>, eof or redo if s/[^.]\K\n/ /' data

sed -e '
   :a
      /\.$/!N
      s/\n/ /
   ta
' data
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` and `fmt`:

```
$ sed -e '1n; s/^[[:upper:]]/\n&/' input.txt | fmt
This is one sentence that is broken.

However this is a good one.

And this one is somehow, broken into many.
```

The sed script inserts a newline before every line that begins with a capital letter (except for the very first line of input).  `sed`'s output is then piped into `fmt` to reformat the resulting paragraphs.

Alternatively use `par` if you have it installed.  It's another paragraph reformatter, but much more capable than `fmt`, with many more features and options.

Note that there will be a blank line between each paragraph.  Paragraphs **should** be separated from each other by at least one blank line. 
 Without the blank lines, your entire input sample is reformatted as a single multi-sentence paragraph, e.g.:

```
$ fmt input.txt
This is one sentence that is broken.  However this is a good one.
And this one is somehow, broken into many.
```

If you need to remove the blank lines after reformatting just pipe it through `sed` again - but this will remove ALL blank lines, including any that may have been in the original input.  e.g.

```
$ sed -e '1n; s/^[[:upper:]]/\n&/' input.txt | fmt | sed -e '/^$/d'
This is one sentence that is broken.
However this is a good one.
And this one is somehow, broken into many.
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Python 3

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'\n([a-z])', r' \1', open('file.txt').read(), flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

This is the same regex/substitution as [Jeff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381908/117037)