# delete specific text based on the next line contents

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need a command to delete specific text based on the contents of the next line, specifically I want to delete "comma" if the next line is "]", and delete that next line "]" as well.

example

```
987678680,
]
123435434-
]
2345643,
]
2345632-
]
234563,
]
1234567654,
]
```

output

```
987678680
123435434-
]
2345643
2345632-
]
234563
1234567654
```

Comment: Please clarify whether the `,` is always at the *end* of the line.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with this kind of task (edit/do something if consecutive lines match a certain pattern) the simplest way to do it with `sed` is probably via the [`N;P;D` cycle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550/22142) aka the *"sliding window"*:

```
sed -e '$!N;s/,\nPATTERN//;t' -e 'P;D' file
```

This gets the `N`ext line into the pattern space and unconditionally attempts to `s`ubstitute per the requirement. It then `t`ests if the replacement was successful: if so, it branches to the end of script (no label) and autoprints the pattern space, otherwise it `P`rints and `D`eletes the first line from the pattern space and restarts the cycle.

---

Another *GNU* `sed` method:

```
sed ':x /,$/{N;s/,\n]//;T x}' file
```

This works correctly even when the trailing comma is on an even-numbered line.  Example:

```
printf '%s\n' 1, 2, ']' | sed ':x /,$/{N;s/,\n]//;T x}'
```

Output:

```
1,
2
```

How it works:

In most programming languages address labels are entirely passive -- labels mark code, but never change the action of that code.  **Not** `sed` though.  In `sed` jumping to a label at the beginning of a program actually changes the action of the code, or rather it avoids the implicit `n`*ext-line* code that a `sed` cycle usually starts with.

The `T`*est and branch if failed* command `T x` checks if the prior `s`*ubstitute* command did nothing, and if so jumps to the `:x` label at the beginning *without* either printing anything or reading a new line.  Which means any odd-numbered line fetched by the *append `N`ext line* that wasn't substituted will be re-scanned, as it should be.

---

For non-*GNU* `sed`, (when the `T` command isn't available and the syntax isn't as permissive), this should be more portable:

```
sed ':x
/,$/{
N
s/,\n]//
t
b x
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used `sed`  as follows:

```
sed -e '/,$/{N; /\]/s/,[^,]*$//;}' file
987678680
123435434-
]
2345643
2345632-
]
234563
1234567654
```

Or per @steeldriver, this can be simplified in `Bash` as follows:

```
sed '$!N; s/,\n]//'
```

Comment: Does it really need to be more complicated than `sed '$!N; s/,\n]//'` ?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! in bash yes but in csh no

Comment: @steeldriver - no, assuming the input will always consist of alternating lines just like the OP sample... Goro, this has _nothing_ to do with `bash` or any shell, really...

Comment: ... most likely because csh is a "great" shell and you have to escape the `!`...

Comment: @agc - how would this "incorrectly delete a `,`" if the next line wasn't a `]` ? You probably mean the opposite: this _would **not** delete a trailing `,`even if the next line was a `]` if the line with the trailing comma was an even line_ ...

Comment: @don_crissti, Thanks.  Worse -- what happened was my eye skipped the `]` in `s,\n]//`, or something like that...  Now rolled back.  (Your opposite note is worth adding however.)

Comment: Actually you may safely remove the `$!` portion from `N`, since if the last line happened to be one with a trailing comma no next line follows it.

Comment: @agc - no problem. I'll leave my note as a comment

Comment: This answer won't work if the input is `printf '%s\n' 1, 2, ']'`.