# Use SED to remove the last two lines and the comma that precedes them

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
    FD488AFF,
    FED6ECFF,
    FFA2A2FF,
    FFD7D8FF,
(
)
```

This also has a newline character after the last `)` character. I am using the macOS terminal and looking for a way to remove the **last comma**, the **(**, and the last **)**, and the **return characters following them**.

```
,
(
)
```

and the new line character following the last **)** character, but I can't seem to get this to work. I don't have to use `sed`, but it does need to be using the terminal.

Comment: @scott you are ranting.

Comment: @Scott I use a colorpicker app called Colorsnapper2. It does everything I need it to do besides sync between computers. I use 3 different computers for web development depending on if I'm on the road, or at home, or at work. The short of it is I'm writing a few scripts to backup and restore the current colors I'm using in the app, and using a cloud service to sync them between computers. I don't need to explain in detail why I need to do it, as it doesn't matter to you. I asked a fairly simple question. I didn't ask for advice on if I should do this or why I shouldn't. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Reverse the file, remove the first 2 lines and remove the comma on the 3rd line. Then re-reverse the results.

```
tac file | sed '1,2d; 3s/,$//' | tac
```

---

To save back into the same file:

```
... | tac > tmp && mv tmp file
```

or, using `sponge` from the `moreutils` package:

```
... | tac | sponge file
```

---

On second thought, this will be a great way to do it: ed is actually a *file editor* so you can make your edits and save.

```
ed file <<'END'
$-1,$d
$s/,$//
wq
END
```

Comment: Original solution!  **+1**

Answer (score 2):

Not the most effective, but should do the job:

```
sed '$d' file | sed '$d' | sed '$s/,$//'
    FD488AFF,
    FED6ECFF,
    FFA2A2FF,
    FFD7D8FF
```

Comment: s/effective/efficient/ -- this solution is perfectly effective.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last two lines if they contain a left and respectively a right paren and the comma that precedes them you could use a sliding window:

```
sed  '1N;$!N;${
s/,\n(\n)//
}
P;D' infile
```

This pulls in a `N`ew line when on `1`st line and then it always keeps three lines in the pattern space (via a [`N;P;D cycle`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550/22142)). When it gets to the la`$`t line, it attempts<sup>1</sup> to remove a comma followed by a `\n`ewline, a `(`, another `\n`ewline and a `)`

---

<sup>1: no need to anchor here since there can't be more than three lines in the pattern space at any time</sup>

Comment: This doesn't edit the file in-place. Consult the manual to see if your `sed` supports editing in place and what is the syntax. If not supported use a temporary file e.g. `sed 'code' infile > outfile && mv outfile infile`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way of doing it with one sed command since you want to remove the last , but it is not the last line.  Here is a way I found to do it using a pipe:

```
sed -e '/^[()]/d' _file_ | sed -e '$s/,$//'
```

The first sed removes the lines that start with ( or ).  The second sed removes the comma at the end of a line from the last line only.

Comment: The requirement is not "delete lines beginning with ( or )", it is "delete last 2 lines"

Answer (score -1):

## To remove last two lines by content

see @LewisM's answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483043/4778

## To remove last two lines by position, and the comma from end of 3rd from end.

```
< «file-name»  head -n -2 | sed -r -e '$ s/,$//'
```

or

```
< «file-name»  sed -nr -e 'x;${d;x;d};1d;p' | sed -r -e '$ s/,$//'
```

Comment: (I have a down vote) Does it not answer the question? Dose it not work? I did test it, and it does work on Debian. Apparently not all `head`s can except negative numbers. That is why I have given a pure `sed` implementation of it.