# Swap a line with another

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have the file

```
Line 1
Line 2 MATCH
Line 3
Line 4
Line 1
Line 2 MATCH
Line 3
Line 4
```

And I want to swap the line with "MATCH" and "Line 1" for every case. I tried to search in other questions, but those move the line with the match to the last line and I don't understand so well the code to remake my version for a final output like:

```
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
```

Comment: Is the line with "MATCH" always line two, hence to be swapped with the line before it?

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes, it is.

Comment: @don_crissti but in the answer provided there, they only swap the line N with the line below. For swap line N with the line above, they swap the Line N-1 with the line below. There is some way to swap with the line above based on a pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the idea is to swap the `MATCH` line with the immediately preceding one, then something like this would do:

```
$ awk '!/MATCH/ { if (NR > 1) print prev; prev=$0} 
        /MATCH/ {print $0;} 
        END {print prev}' < file
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
```

The script holds the previous line in `prev`, printing and updating it on the non-matching lines. On lines matching the pattern, it prints the current line, leaving the previous in the variable to be printed next.

Special cases for the first line (`NR==1`) when there's no previous line to print, and for the `END` when we print the held line.

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed` with a [`N;P;D cycle`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216550/22142):

```
sed -e '$!N;s/\(Line 1\)\(\n\)\(.*MATCH.*\)/\3\2\1/;t' -e 'P;D' infile
```

This will swap only if the line with `MATCH` is preceded by `Line 1`: the `t` without label branches to the end of script if successful and so it avoids another swap if any `Line 1` is followed by consecutive lines with `MATCH`. Adjust the regex for any leading/trailing blanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ed`:

```
$ printf 'g/MATCH/m-2\n,p\n' | ed -s file
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
Line 2 MATCH
Line 1
Line 3
Line 4
```

The `m` command moves the current line after to the subsequent target address.  Here, we find all lines matching `MATCH` (it's the `g` in front of the regular expression that makes this a "global" operation), and for each line move it one line up (to "after the line two lines up").  The effect is that the `MATCH` lines swap places with the immediately preceding lines.

The final `,p` in the editing script just displays the modified editing buffer.  This could be changed to something like `wq` to write the changed editing buffer back to the original file.

Note that using `ed` for editing files might look neat, but is not recommended for large files as the whole file is read into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` editor, we can swap two lines one of which contains Match keyword with the one preceding it.

```
 $ sed -e '
       /MATCH/!{
         x;1!p;$!d;g;q
       }
       $G
   '  input.txt

 Line 2 MATCH
 Line 1
 Line 3
 Line 4
 Line 2 MATCH
 Line 1
 Line 3
 Line 4
```

Answer (score -1):

sed "s/line 2 match//g"|sed "s/line 1/line 2 match\n&/g"

Above command worked fine

Comment: The lines with `MATCH` should swap places with the preceding lines.